# Parasitic draw and Ohm's law?

Tags: voltage

Suppose you have a parasitic draw on a car battery (e.g. dome light is on) and you measure the current draw at the battery, say 1 amp. Now you turn the dome light off and the current draw goes down to milliamps. But in turning off the light you have lowered the resistance also. So how does this work with Ohm's law, as resistance and current are inversely related for a given voltage?

Comment: *But in turning off the light you have lowered the resistance also* - resistance of what? By turning off something you are *increasing* the resistance to nearly infinite one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the light is off, then the circuit is open which raises the resistance to infinity ie. no current flows.  If there is still a draw and the light is not on, then the switch did not completely open which means it has some high level of resistance that does not allow enough current to flow to light the light. Another possibility is that there is another circuit draining the battery.
In the case of the switch opening completely (infinite resistance) using Ohm's Law we can see that:
$$I=\frac{V}{R}$$

$$I=\frac{12volts}{\infty}$$

$$I=0$$